# let express.js redirect all sub-path of any html file path to itself

Tags: express, routes

I have this code on file `server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { join } = require('path');
const app = express();
app
  .get(':path.html/*', (req, rep) => {
    rep.sendFile(join(__dirname, req.params.path+'.html'));
  })
  .listen(8080)
```

I run it (`node server.js`) then when I visit

- `http://localhost:8080/foo.html/aaa` or
- `http://localhost:8080/foo.html/bbb/ccc`

I get the content of `foo.html`.
This works for any html file of `./*.html`

I would like this works for any html file of `./**/*.html`
For example when I visit `http://localhost:8080/sub/dir/bar.html/foo` I want to get content of sub/dir/bar.html

how to do that with express router syntax?

Comment: Probably need to use a regex expression for your router syntax.

Comment: Though I must say, I don't understand why you would do this.  A wrong resource URL is a wrong URL.  At best, you could redirect to your best guess at what the URL should be, but don't just render your best guess for the content. If anyone links to you with a wrong URL, that will make search engines think your site has pages it doesn't really have and maybe even refer people there.  The proper response would be either a 404 error or a 301 redirect.  The 301 can end up with the same result for the user, but will be advising search engines or other agents appropriately.